# Tensorflow_datasets import issue "Python int too large to convert to C long"

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

[Error with Tensorflow_datasets import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5zpc.png)

Comment: In my case it is working fine on Ubuntu but not with windows. In both OS I have the same anaconda configurations, but I am unable to find what might be the problem in windows.

Comment: Please provide the question and the code in the question description, not everyhting as a pitcure. Try to explain your problem widely .